# How can i find c of the interval (0, c) for which we reject H0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have tried so many different ways to do this one problem, but i cant see the logic behind any of my results.

The problem is :

*We have a small sample of 7 variables ( 2.05, 1.92, 1.34, 4.67, 2.26, 4.95, 2.38). We suppose the population follows a uniform distribution over the interval (0, b), where b is an unknown parameter.
We give b0 = 5 and we want to confront the following hypothesis : H0: b = b0 ;  H1 : b < b0.
What estimateur should we use ?*

For this part of the question, i am truly unsure for what kind of estimateur would be appropriate for this since we are looking at the upper bound of our interval. I have used x bar ( x with - on top but i dont know how to format it). I have also simply used b since it is our unknown parameter and it also makes sense with what we are trying to see.

(please note : this is a "introduction" course to statistics so we are not using complicated formulas)

*For alpha = 0.05, the critical interval for which we reject H0 is (0, c) where c is a constant. Find the value of c for the case we are concerned with.*

Ok, this is where i am losing my mind.
I have tried 2 different method to try and find a somehow logical answer to this question:

1. I have used the technique we always use in class (we actually never had one where the hypothesis was toward bound and not the means) : find the sample means, find the variance then the standard derivation. Then assume the sample means follows a normal distribution then use the formula P{X bar - mu > epsilon |H0} to find epsilon. When all this is done, i found an interval with b - epsilon.
   I dont really know why but this makes no sense to me. I have amazing grades in this classe but this problem really grinds my gears because it works onto assumption that i dont think are right.
2. I have found a CDF for the sample we have. Since the population is uniformly distributed i supposed the sample had a cdf of 1/b^7. Then i found the pdf : (x/b)^7.  To find c, i replaced x with c b by 5 since H0 states that b0 = 5 = b. Then found a value for c. How ever, again this does not feel right... We have never proved or disproved any hypothesis using the CDF and PDF in this course so this to be the correct way to approche the problem is very bizarre and doesn't feel right.

*Should we reject H0?*

Well every technique i have used all come to the same conclusion : yes!

*Find the p value of our estimate for b. Is it high or low?*

I was very not sure how to do this, so i used the value of b0 = 5 and the highest value of the sample we have : 4.95. With P{5 > (x/5)^7 > 4.95} = p, got (5^7 - 4.95^7)/5^7 ... p = 0.068.
Does that make sense? i really aimed in the dark for this one, since the p value is kind of weird since it is not for a seams like we usually work with.

Am I missing the target here? This hole problem is the doum of my existence for the past week, i cant figure out how to do it and actually agree with my results. Again, i have amazing grands in the course, so i kind of trust my guts on my results... But these results are not looking like they work!

Could anyone show me the light at the end of the dark tunnel? I just want to know if any of my method is somehow right! *Sorry for the grammar and all, english is my second language!*

Comment: In this case it is customary to use the maximum value of your sample to estimate parameter $b.$ Of course, $\max(X_i)< b$ always, but you can find the dist'n of the max of a sample of $n$ and use that as a guide to find an _unbiased_ estimator of $b$ or to test a hypothesis about $b.$ You are on the right track. Maybe look at beta distributions.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for your answer, i will definitely try to redo it with the maximum value of b. Thanks